# How to use the "domain_exists()" function

Tags: multisite

How do one use the [`domain_exists()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/domain_exists) function with an example.

I have checked [the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/domain_exists#Usage), but it didn't help

Answer (score 5):

`domain_exists()` is something you probably won´t call by yourself.

It is used in the registration/creation process of new sites in a Multisite installation. There it´s used to check if a specific blog URL is already in use:

```
if ( domain_exists($mydomain, $path, $current_site->id) )
    $errors->add( 'blogname', __( 'Sorry, that site already exists!' ) );
```

[(From `/wp-includes/ms-functions.php`, line 612-613)](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/ms-functions.php#L612)

The "normal" Codex also has a page about it: [mu_exists()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/domain_exists)

You can see that it was introduced with the Multisite functionality in WP 3.5, [it´s defined in lines 1256-1259 of `/wp-includes/ms-functions.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/ms-functions.php#L1256)

```
function domain_exists($domain, $path, $site_id = 1) {
    global $wpdb;
    $path = trailingslashit( $path );
    $result = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT blog_id FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE domain = %s AND path = %s AND site_id = %d", $domain, $path, $site_id) );
}
```

All in all you most probably don´t want to call it yourself. If you want to check for an existent site or something like that, there are more comfortable functions like [`wp_get_blogs()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_sites).